# Array Print Integers to Text File from First to Last

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

So I'm at a point in my program where the method must call the previous method passing in the string "Enter output file name: " using a dialog box, it must open the output text file with that name and then it must print the integers to the file from the first to the last and then close the file. There should be no return value.

The main method was provided by the instructor and is not to be changed, and the issue appears in the last (third) method called print. I get the error that "in" cannot be resolved to a variable and therefore my program will not run.

Do I need to create a scanner or simply modify my PrintWriter for the output file? Any help you are able to provide me is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class Project5 
{
    static final int LIMIT = 25;    // Max ints in array

public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

    int [] numbers = new int [LIMIT];
    int count = getInput(numbers);  // Calls getInput Method

    System.out.println (count + " values were read.");
    print (numbers, count);   // prints original list
    sort (numbers, count);    // calls the sort method
    print (numbers, count);   // prints sorted list

    System.out.println("Program complete.");
}   

/**
 * This method gets the input text file name from the user through the use of a dialog box.
 * It then returns the string entered by the user.
 * @param prompt, the dialog box presented to the user requesting the input file name.
 */
public static String getFileName (String prompt)
{
    // Read in a string from a dialog box
    String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
    return in;
}

/**
 * This method gets the user's input from the previous method, opens the text file and stores the integers into the array.
 * It then returns the count of how many values are read and closes the file.
 * @param numbers, array to be filled with the integers from the input text file
 */
public static int getInput (int[] numbers)
{
    String inputFileName = getFileName("Enter input file name: "); // call getFileName method passing in string "Enter input file name"
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);                      // open input text file with that name
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // read integers from file and store into array
    int count = 0;
    while (input.hasNextInt() && count < numbers.length) // integers to read and array is not full
    {
        numbers[count] = input.nextInt(); 
        count++;
    }
    input.close();   
    return count;    
}

/**
 * This method calls the getFileName method, opens the output text file   with the given name,
 * and prints the integers to the file from the first to the last.
 * @param numbers, the array to be counted
 * @param count, the number of integers in array
 */
public static void print (int[] numbers, int count) // array to print and count of how many integers are in the array
{
    String outputFileName = getFileName("Enter output file name: ");   // Call getFileName
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);   // Create output file

    // print integers to file from first to last
    int position = 0;
    while (position < numbers.length)
    {
        output.print(in.nextInt); // THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK
        position++;
    }
    output.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the numbers from the input stored in `numbers`. There is no point attempting to read them again. All you need to do is perform array access to get each element at the given `position`:

```
output.print(numbers[position]);
```

Arrays are 0-indexed for Java, so given the array containing prime numbers for example, named `array`:

```
array[0] -> 2
array[1] -> 3
array[2] -> 5
array[3] -> 7
array[4] -> 11
...
```

---

Your looping condition is also presumably wrong. You print all the numbers in the array (`position < numbers.length`)

Whilst, I'm presuming you just want to print the `count` number of numbers:

```
while (position < count) { 
    // ...
```

---

It is also important to note that you should flush the output before closing it.

So,

```
output.flush();
output.close();
```